# Converting a number to binary and back as a test in Java

Tags: java, performance, floating-point

This is one of my first takes on Java, coming mainly from Matlab I found I had many things to learn.
The code will try to convert a number into an array of ones and zeros and then do the opposite returning you the original number (or at least something very close to it, as it is hard to return the exact number). It is not tested very well, so I can only tell that it is symmetric and not that it is correct.

It would be nice to know any errors I have made, or things that I could improve. An idea I had was using BigInt, I have read about it but not yet used it.

If you could focus on the language specific issues and kindly point them out I would be grateful.

```
package baseconversion;

import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class FloatToBin{

    public static double pow2(double a, double b) {
        return a * (java.lang.Math.pow(2, b));
    }

    public static double rem(double a, double b) {
        return a % b;
    }

    public static double fix(double val) {
        if (val < 0) {
            return Math.ceil(val);
        }
        return Math.floor(val);
    }

    public static double vConv(int[] a, double[] b) {
        int aRows = a.length;
        int bRows = b.length;
        double c = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < aRows; i++) { 
                c += a[i] * b[i];
        }
        return c;
    }

    public static void main(String []args){
        double a = 340.3562; 
        int n = 20;   
        int m = 20;

        int count = 0;

        int[] out = new int[n + m];       

        for (int i = -(n-1); i <= m; i++) {
             out[count] = (int)rem(a * pow2(1, (double)i), 2);
             count++;
        } 

        double[] temp = new double[n + m];
        double origVal;
        count--;
        int revCount = 0; 

        for (int ii = n - 1; ii >= -m; ii--) {
             temp[revCount] = pow2(1, (double)ii);
             count--;
             revCount++;
        }

        origVal = vConv(out, temp);      

        System.out.println("Original number is:");
        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println("Binary representation is:");
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(out));
        System.out.println("Inverting we get:");
        System.out.println(origVal);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview, green_leaf. I hope you get some fine answers!

Comment: Are you sure the code works? An example run is: `Original number is:
41.52
Binary representation is:
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1]
Inverting we get:
0.5199995040893555`

Comment: Maybe  you only care about the decimal part?

Comment: @Caridorc I am sorry for that, I was struggling with java and did not notice the error. Please do try the updated version.

Comment: @green_leaf thanks for the fast fixing :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Cryptic names

```
int n = 10;   
int m = 20;
```

Please give longer and more descriptive names to n and m

### Overworked main

I would define outside of main

```
public static double FloatToBin(float n) {

}

public static double BinToFloat(bin n) {

}
```

So that main can contain the IO only.

Comment: In academia I rarely (never) encountered anyone who cares about things like that. My professor always said that if the numbers are correct then it does not matter, trust that the next guy will know the theory. I suppose professional programmers are very careful with that sort of thing though. Thank you for your input.

Comment: @green_leaf - It's ok for you to c9e w2h w5r s3m you l2e but you c4t a4e the r4r w2l u7d. J2t so l2g as you get ok r4s.

Comment: @rolfl ...... what?

Comment: I'm just "trusting" that @green_leaf knows the theory behind my naming convention... right? - in case you were not aware, I have put the first letter, and last letter of each word, and then, if there are more than 1 letter in between, I have indicated how many there are...

Comment: @rolfl .......... right :)

Comment: @rolfl yup, that was exactly the idea :)
Let whoever has to deal with my code figure everything out, I don't have time to deal with that, plus I have the numbers that I wanted to and its really late...let me just write a comment wishing good luck to whoever might need this in the future and I'm done.

Comment: In a more serious tone though, I do hope that by hanging out here I will learn how to do things properly, all constructive criticism is welcomed and expected.

Comment: In which case, your intentional laziness and the professor who suggests it are a liability to the industry. Code is written once, and read many times. Making the code hard to read is egotistical, arrogant, and a disservice to yourself and others.

Comment: There is no industry rolfl, it usually boils down to us working in a lab for some paper. None usually sees the code except us. You have to admit that there is a difference in code that is developed for an experiment and code that is done for a company or whatever, because I have seen other peoples code too. And when they are struggling for good results at 10 in the evening its really hard to complain to them about naming conventions.

Comment: @green_leaf the fact is that it's sloppy, and it doesn't matter if "None usually sees the code.." - we are looking at it now - it's the same as saying "I don't need to debug the code because.. it usually works" - at some point karma will catch up to you and you will be the "future person" trying to understand your code.. and at that point you will wish you had more documentation than a "good luck figuring this out" comment.

Comment: Related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/17781/why-do-many-talented-scientists-write-horrible-software. Also, try to be proud of the code you write.

Comment: @green_leaf I used to think like you: "no one will see this but me".  But as years passed I had the need to go back and look back at my old code.  For example, I either wanted to reuse the code in another application or rerun it with modifications.  And I found that I no longer remembered what all those cryptic variables meant.  So it's good to get in the habit of making things readable, if only for your future self's sake.

Comment: I never disagreed with the notion. The fact that I am here and trying to improve the way I code means that I do understand the importance of Caridorcs' comments, and/or that I have indeed been in the position user2813274 describes.

Comment: One quick question, I use _int []_ to store my vector of numbers, but I know about the existence of _ArrayList<Integer>_. In general would I gain something from using it?

Answer (score 2):

Use imports consistently. You've fully qualified `java.lang.Math.pow` but imported `java.lang.Math` and called `Math.floor`. Do one or the other (the second being better). You can also statically import methods, e.g. `import static java.lang.Math.pow` and then just call `pow(2, b)`.

The rem function seems a bit pointless to me. I'd just inline it.

The pow2 function is always called with a == 1. Ged rid of the argument. Then get rid of the function and just call pow(2, x) directly.

Comment: Thank you for the import consistency comment, I scrolled up at my code the moment I read it, and it makes no sense using both ways.
**pow2** is the way it is in order to remain consistent with the Matlab version. **rem** indeed should not be there, again I just copied it from matlab.